# ffmpeg extract frame timestamps from video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using this [library](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) to use FFmpeg with my Android application. I am extracting frames from a video and then adding them to a crop viewer. So each frame needs to represent some time frame within the video. Here is my current ffmpeg code to extract the frames:

`ffmpeg -i inputFile -f image2 -ss mySS -r myR frame-%05d.png`

When using the above command how would I add a timestamp to each frame? So i know for example frame 5 is at 9s within the video.

I dont know if the ffmpeg lib I am using has ffprobe from this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/841872/how-do-i-extract-the-timestamps-associated-with-frames-ffmpeg-extracts-from-a-vi). I have also looked at other links on stackoverflow

any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you want the info in the filename or in the image?

Comment: I dont mind as long as it is quick and I can put each timeframe into a variable. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

`frame_pts` option is your friend... set it to true and ffmpeg will output the frame's presentation timestamp as your filename.

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i file -vsync 0 -frame_pts true out%d.png
```

Credits goes to this [superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1421195/890179).. more explanation of mixing framerate `-r` option with `frame_pts`

Answer (score 8):

To burn the timestamp in the video:

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile -vf drawtext=fontfile='/path/to/font':fontcolor=white:fontsize=25:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-th-10:text='Source time: %{pts}' -ss mySS -r myR frame-%05d.png
```

If you have a > Nov 13 2017 build of FFmpeg, you can run

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile -f image2 -vf select='gte(t,mySS)' -vsync 0 -frame_pts 1 frame-%05d.png
```

This will number the output frames with the source frame index.

If you can't upgrade FFmpeg, then there's a longer workaround.

Run

```
ffmpeg -i inputFile -f image2 -vf select='gte(t,mySS)',showinfo -vsync 0 frame-%05d.png 2> log.txt
```

This will redirect the console to a text file. In it, you will lines like this:

```
...
     Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.1.100 wrapped_avframe
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 00000000056d9dc0] n:   0 pts:  38400 pts_time:3       pos:   105928 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:F6027584 plane_checksum:[FAA4D7FC 4748A9ED 4767F37D] mean:[123 129 126] stdev:[57.1 78.2 80.6]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 00000000056d9dc0] n:   1 pts:  38912 pts_time:3.04    pos:   101527 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:P checksum:ECBC791A plane_checksum:[4104BBD1 4805B985 542303B5] mean:[123 129 126] stdev:[57.1 78.1 80.5]
[Parsed_showinfo_1 @ 00000000056d9dc0] n:   2 pts:  39424 pts_time:3.08    pos:   108798 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 s:320x240 i:P iskey:0 type:B checksum:70B2AC23 plane_checksum:[EF78A2F1 946CDA4F 39B72ED4] mean:[123 129 127] stdev:[57.1 77.8 80.1]
...
```

You can parse and extract the pts_time values, which have a 1:1 correspondence with the produced images.

Comment: i definitely cant use the 2nd command because i think the libs version is v3.0.1. Also i dont want the timeframe on the image i need to assign it to a variable. It would be convenient if I could name each frames filename as the time of the frame in the video or any other way i can put them into variables. thanks alot

Comment: Would you be able to help me with my updated question in comment? thanks :)

Comment: `Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'mySS)'` for me...

Comment: I see - `mySS` is the seeking parameter...